# What step blocks mail forwarded from own domain to gmail

Tags: gmail, email-server, zoneedit

I have my own (personal) domain where all email sent to this domain is forwarded to my Gmail account. For this purpose I use the ZoneEdit MailForward function.

Since about 3 days (without changing any DNS records), my email does not arrive anymore on my gmail account. I have 1 other domains where emails are forwarded in a similar way (to the same gmail account), but they do still arrive.

What can be the reason that the email does not arrive anymore? The domain (website) is still active and has not yet expired. Is there some sort of mail policy introduced (like SPF?) that prevents mail forwarding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

zoneedit has been having problems with their mail forwarding for almost a week now.  I noticed it when emails sent to my forwarded domain didn't arrive and people asked me what was up.  I experimented with changing the forwarding to point to several completely different destination accounts with no luck.  Then I used telnet to connect to port 25 of mail.zoneedit.com and test the connection and found that the mail server is rejecting connections due to it being unable to do a reverse address lookup on the IP address of the system attempting to connect, presumably a mail server attempting to send a message to the mail forwarder.

I've already placed a couple of tech support calls with the company that owns Zoneedit, they're aware of the problem and tell me the guys that manage the server in Vancouver, BC are working on the problem.  It troubles me that it has been going on this long and still hasn't been resolved.

Comment: Ah, that would explain a lot! By running my own mail server I now managed to receive emails from my domain again.

Comment: It looks like zoneedit solved their problems. I initially set up dnsexit for receiving my mail, but I can now use zoneedit in cobmination with gmail again.

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting any bouncebacks?

It's very likely that Google is blocking your email. Generally, forwarding all email from one location to another can be a bad idea, particularly to somewhere like Google. If you're getting any spam at your domain's email address, it all gets forwarded to Google as well. When Google sees that, they see it as coming from YOUR domain, and not the originator. This is a quick way to get blocked.

I'd recommend setting up something like Google Apps instead, if you would like Google to be picking up your email for your domain.

As for an SPF record, I'm not sure how strict Google is about SPF records for incoming email. However, if it was the SPF being the problem you would likely be getting a bounceback.

Have you watched the maillogs to see what happens when the mail gets forwarded to Google?

Comment: Thanks nate, I do not have mail records as ZoneEdit does not provide them. I've tried to forward all mail to another mail address (zoho) but this does not help, maybe they have the same policy as google. Is there another way to see if google is ignoring email from my domain?

Comment: Can I set-up google apps to do a "catch-all" for email to my domain as I have a lot of email addresses?

Comment: In regards to checking for more info on whether Google is blocking them or if there is another issue, I'd definitely recommend taking a look at the maillogs. Also, I just remembered you can have Google also pick up your email via POP3. So you could do that and wouldn't have to bother with Google Apps or forwarding. If you login to GMail, you should be able to do that by going to the Gear -> Settings -> Accounts -> Add a POP3 mail account you own.

Comment: The problem is that I do not have a mail server that can receive my mail. I have a domain registration where I can change the MX records, but until now I could use ZoneEdit to forward all my mail to my Gmail account. From there, I 'popped' my mail back to my own server (a bit of work-around because my ISP seems to block port 25).

Comment: Ah, I see, sorry I misunderstood. I'm not too sure on the best way to fix that, then...I'll see if I can think of anything.